# Linux file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I have two questions regarding linux file permissions.

## 1)

I have the directory /share with the following permissions:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -ld /share/
drwxrwxrwx. 4 root root 4096 Aug 29 09:15 /share/
```

Now I go as user erich to that directory and create a file:

```
[erich@localhost share]$ touch file
[erich@localhost share]$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 erich share      0 Aug 29 09:30 file
```

Now as user sven I delete the file:

```
[sven@localhost share]$ rm -f file
[sven@localhost share]$
```

How is that possible? Only erich has read/write permissions. I noticed that when I change the /share folder's permission to e.g. 755, then sven cannot delete the file. Is the parent's directory overwriting the files' permissions in it and if yes, why?

## 2)

I want to share that /share folder to everybody, but at least for sven and erich. I created a group "share" and put those users in it. Then I did the test:

```
[erich@localhost share]$ mkdir erich
[erich@localhost share]$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x. 2 erich share      6 Aug 29 09:28 erich
[erich@localhost share]$ touch erich/erich
[erich@localhost share]$ ls -l erich/
-rw-r--r--. 1 erich share 0 Aug 29 09:28 erich
```

User sven has no write permission to "file". How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact that directory permissions are named in the same way, they are kind of different from the file permissions.
For folder:

- `r` is for listing content of the folder
- `w` for creating and deleting files
- `x` for making that directory current (`cd` in it).

That's why user can delete file with `w` switched on, even if it has no write permission for the file itself.

Directory permissions doesn't force permission on file you create within it; so, after you create file with `touch`, you should make it group-writable. You can change permissions of all files in the directory with `chmod 775 -R share` (`-R` means recursively).

Comment: I always thought that the permissions I see on a file are the effective permissions on the file and not just make believe. Am I wrong with that picture? What's the use of assigning permissions to a file then?

Comment: Making "chmod ..." every time a user creates a file or directory is not practical and not possible for users on a remote Windows.

Comment: Default file permissions for newly created files are controlled by umask: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

Comment: umask seems to be system wide, but I want to change the setting for only one folder.  At least for the file sharing problem I found the solutuion in the man page of smb.conf: use the flags "force directory mode = 777" and "force create mode = 777"

Comment: Using samba isn't related to the original question.